# Android WiFi Debugging -> Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-debug, adb

I managed to debug my app through wifi but I can't see no logcat in Android Studio, I just managed to see the logcat in adb terminal with command `adb -s x.x.x.x:5555 logcat` but you can understand it's quite messy. Is it possible to see it in Android Studio? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you run `adb connect <ip_address>:5555` from the terminal the connected device will appear under the 'Android Monitor' tab in Android Studio, allowing you to see the usual logcat output.